# Hiding Controller And ActionMethods in Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When We Have Multiple Url's In Mvc ..when we click url i want to open in browser with out showing Action Index name and Controller Name in the browser How it possible in MVC

Comment: Do you mean do not show the URL at all, i.e. hide the navigation bar? or change the URL so that the controller/action are not in the URL?

Comment: You can use Custom Routing in mvc